# R regular expression to split string column into multiple columns

Tags: regex, r, split, multiple-columns

I have a column as follows in a dataframe called PeakBoundaries:

```
           chrom
 chr11:69464719-69502928
 chr7:55075808-55093954
 chr8:128739772-128762863
 chr3:169389459-169490555
 chr17:37848534-37877201
 chr19:30306758-30316875
 chr1:150496857-150678056
 chr12:69183279-69260755
 chr11:77610143-77641464
 chr8:38191804-38260814
 chr12:58135797-58156509
```

I would like to separate out the columns so that the columns look like below in a dataframe:

```
chr       chrStart           chrEnd
chr11     69464719         69502928
chr7      55075808         55093954
chr8      128739772        128762863
chr3      169389459        169490555
```

etc.

I have tried a regular expression approach but am not getting anywhere in terms of getting the match to enter into a new column:

```
 PeakBoundaries$chrOnly <- PeakBoundaries[grep("\\w+?=\\:"),PeakBoundaries$chrom]
```

I am met with the error:
      Error in `[.data.frame`(PeakBoundaries, grep("\w+?=\:"), PeakBoundaries$chrom) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Is it `PeakBoundaries` or `PeakBoudaries`?

Comment: PeakBoundaries. Thats a typo in the question rather than the code ;)

Comment: Please correct. Do you have extra space(s) in the name of your column in "PeakBoundaries"?

Comment: no there are no extra spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - no regex needed, just the `strsplit` function:

```
dat <- read.table(text="chr11:69464719-69502928
chr7:55075808-55093954
chr8:128739772-128762863
chr3:169389459-169490555
chr17:37848534-37877201
chr19:30306758-30316875
chr1:150496857-150678056
chr12:69183279-69260755
chr11:77610143-77641464
chr8:38191804-38260814
chr12:58135797-58156509", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat[,2:4] <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(dat[,1],split = "\\:|\\-")), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

colnames(dat) <- c("chrom", "chr", "chrStart", "chrEnd")

# Convert last two columns from character to numeric:

dat$chrStart <- as.numeric(dat$chrStart)
dat$chrEnd <- as.numeric(dat$chrEnd)
```

Results

```
> res

                      chrom   chr  chrStart    chrEnd
1   chr11:69464719-69502928 chr11  69464719  69502928
2    chr7:55075808-55093954  chr7  55075808  55093954
3  chr8:128739772-128762863  chr8 128739772 128762863
4  chr3:169389459-169490555  chr3 169389459 169490555
5   chr17:37848534-37877201 chr17  37848534  37877201
6   chr19:30306758-30316875 chr19  30306758  30316875
7  chr1:150496857-150678056  chr1 150496857 150678056
8   chr12:69183279-69260755 chr12  69183279  69260755
9   chr11:77610143-77641464 chr11  77610143  77641464
10   chr8:38191804-38260814  chr8  38191804  38260814
11  chr12:58135797-58156509 chr12  58135797  58156509
```

**Edit**

You could do everything using only your existing dataframe. Replace `dat[,1]` with `PeakBoundaries$chrom` and `dat[,2:4]` with `PeakBoundaries[,(ncol(PeakBoundaries)+1):(ncol(PeakBoundaries)+3)]` and you should have it!

**Edit  By OP**

OK so I think there's something a bit odd with my dataset but I've sorted it with Dominic's help so that it it is now:

```
  PeakBoundaries <- as.data.frame(PeakBoundaries)
  PeakBoundaries <- PeakBoundaries[-1,]
  PeakBoundaries <- as.data.frame(PeakBoundaries)
  PeakBoundaries$PeakBoundaries <- 
             as.character(PeakBoundaries$PeakBoundaries)
  PeakBoundaries[,(ncol(PeakBoundaries)+1):(ncol(PeakBoundaries)+3)] <- 
             matrix(unlist(strsplit(PeakBoundaries$PeakBoundaries,
                                    split = "\\:|\\-")), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: OK thanks. How do I get my column data into the table you have suggested as the data input?

Comment: OK. Now I have the error Error in strsplit(PeakBoundaries$chrom, split = "\\:|\\-") :   non-character argument

Comment: Are you sure your column is called "chrom" ?

Comment: colnames(PeakBoundaries)
[1] "chrom"

Comment: ok so then try `as.character(PeakBoundaries$chrom)` instead. It's probably a factor.

Comment: Otherwise you could always just use the `dat` as is and combine it to your existing dataframe with `cbind(PeakBoundaries, dat)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74163/discussion-between-dominic-comtois-and-user3632206).

Comment: Dominic: you would need `read.table(..., stringsAsFactors=F)`. Or see my answer for how to avoid using read.table

Comment: Yeah I always have my options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) active and sometimes forget to mention if or include it to the read.table calls.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version of Dominic's answer, making the insertion a one-liner:

```
dat <- data.frame(chrom = readLines(textConnection("chr11:69464719-69502928
chr7:55075808-55093954
chr8:128739772-128762863
chr3:169389459-169490555
chr17:37848534-37877201
chr19:30306758-30316875
chr1:150496857-150678056
chr12:69183279-69260755
chr11:77610143-77641464
chr8:38191804-38260814
chr12:58135797-58156509")) )

dat[, c('chr','chrStart','chrEnd')] <- t( sapply( dat$chrom, function(s) { str_split(s, '[:-]') [[1]] } ) )

dat$chrStart <- as.numeric(dat$chrStart)
dat$chrEnd <- as.numeric(dat$chrEnd)
```

Comment: I think one of the problems I'm having is getting the column from the dataframe into the text format so that read.table can be done. I'm guessing from Dominica earlier answer that I can use the columns directly from the dataframe without going through a read table step?

Comment: I just posted you above code that does that! `dat <- data.frame(chrom = readLines(textConnection(...` instead of `read.table(text=..., header = F)`

Answer (score 1):

We could try

```
library(tidyr)
extract(dat, chrom, into=c('chr', 'chrStart', 'chrEnd'),
                 '([^:]+):([^-]+)-(.*)', convert=TRUE)
#     chr  chrStart    chrEnd
#1  chr11  69464719  69502928
#2   chr7  55075808  55093954
#3   chr8 128739772 128762863
#4   chr3 169389459 169490555
#5  chr17  37848534  37877201
#6  chr19  30306758  30316875
#7   chr1 150496857 150678056
#8  chr12  69183279  69260755
#9  chr11  77610143  77641464
#10  chr8  38191804  38260814
#11 chr12  58135797  58156509
```

Or a faster option using the devel version of `data.table`.  We can install the `v1.9.5` from [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.5+
nm1 <- c('chr', 'chrStart', 'chrEnd')
res <- setDT(tstrsplit(dat$chrom, '[:-]', type.convert=TRUE))
setnames(res, nm1)
res
#      chr  chrStart    chrEnd
# 1: chr11  69464719  69502928
# 2:  chr7  55075808  55093954
# 3:  chr8 128739772 128762863
# 4:  chr3 169389459 169490555
# 5: chr17  37848534  37877201
# 6: chr19  30306758  30316875
# 7:  chr1 150496857 150678056
# 8: chr12  69183279  69260755
# 9: chr11  77610143  77641464
#10:  chr8  38191804  38260814
#11: chr12  58135797  58156509
```

Or

```
library(splitstackshape)
setnames(cSplit(dat, 'chrom', ':|-',fixed=FALSE,
                      type.convert=TRUE), nm1)[]
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(chrom = structure(c(2L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
5L, 3L, 11L, 4L), .Label = c("chr1:150496857-150678056",
"chr11:69464719-69502928", 
"chr11:77610143-77641464", "chr12:58135797-58156509", 
"chr12:69183279-69260755", 
"chr17:37848534-37877201", "chr19:30306758-30316875",
 "chr3:169389459-169490555", 
"chr7:55075808-55093954", "chr8:128739772-128762863",
 "chr8:38191804-38260814"
 ), class = "factor")), .Names = "chrom", row.names = c(NA, -11L
 ), class = "data.frame")
```